Relationship between the Berezinskii–Kosterlitz–Thouless (BKT) transition and the Wilson-Fisher (WF) fixed point
The Wilson-Fisher (WF) fixed point, in $\mathrm O(N)$, $N \geq 2$ models, is the point in parameter space where the correlation length diverges, yielding scale-free behavior and indicating a phase transition.
In three dimensions, this is accompanied by a spontaneous symmetry breaking, giving rise to long range order $\langle \varphi_i \rangle \neq 0$.
The critical properties of this transition, mainly scaling exponents, are described by the Wilson-Fisher fixed point in Renormalization group (RG) flow.
Now, by the Mermin-Wagner theorem, spontaneous symmetry breaking (of a continuous symmetry) does not happen in two dimensions, even though mean-field theory suggests so.
This does, however, not preclude a phase transition, and in fact, there is one to quasi long-range order, $\langle \varphi \rangle \sim 1 / r^\eta$, the Berezinskii–Kosterlitz–Thouless (BKT) transition.
This transition is described by the un-binding of vortex pairs, and as I understand it, there is a different RG-approach of the effective theory of vortices in terms of a Coloumb gas.
However, can the BKT-fixed point be though of as the same fixed-point as the Wilson-Fisher fixed point, only approached using a different description of the physics?
One can do the regular $\mathrm O(2)$ RG, performed the $\epsilon$ expansion, calculate the properties of the WF fixed point with $\epsilon = 2$.
This might not give quantitative good prediction, but is it at all capturing the physics?
Or, is the BKT transition a separate phenomenon, not related to the symmetry breaking transition we see in three dimensions?
In other words, is the familiar RG procedure capturing anything about the critical behavior of the $\mathcal O(2)$ models in two dimensions, or is it just invalid?

First of all, WF fixed point ceases to exist precisely at $d=2$.  You can convince yourself that, if you attempt to expand down from $d=4$, the $\phi^2$ terms blows up in the IR as $d \rightarrow 2$ and you have no way to tame it.  The proper way is to take the non-linear sigma model and $\epsilon$ expand up from $d=2$.  But even then you will miss BKT, because you only get WF for $d>2$.  BKT is completely something else, special to 2D, and has nothing to do with symmetry breaking.

Thanks, @T.P.Ho, that pretty much answers my question. If you add that as an answer, I will give it a check.
